# aapt error for Dump badging

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, aapt

ok i m getting this problem out of the blue , not sure what is causing it, when i upload the apk to play store it says

> Failed to run aapt dump badging: AndroidManifest.xml:425: error: ERROR
>   getting 'name' attribute: attribute is not a string value

how ever the manifest seems fine here

```
<activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0b0142"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f0802ab"
        android:name="<absolute path like a.b.c.activityname>"
        android:launchMode="1"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:parentActivityName="absolute path like a.b.c.activityname" />
```

off course above look up was done in apk analyzer on final manifest.

did verify by running locally all below no errors

aapt dump strings
aapt dump permissions 
aapt dump resources
aapt dump configurations

the error how ever do appear when i do **dump badging**

> ERROR getting 'name' attribute: attribute is not a string value

also

> aapt list -v -a

this is very confusing as to why activity name is it being resolved by string even when it has the form **a.c.b...activityname** any thoughts any one? what is going on here

[image]

Comment: have you edited the output for posting? Why are there "<" and  ">" symbols in the name entry? That seems suspicious for an XML file. The [api doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) is clear that the field is a string and should be a fully qualified class name or use the short hand method.

Comment: I edited the value for posting here, yeah there are no <> in xml, plus this apk compiles and runs fine aapt is failing for dump badging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it fixed the aapt is reporting wrong error

The simple solution/workaround is to **not** use a string resource for the category name.

```
<category android:name="@string/example" >
```

replace with:

```
<category android:name="com.example.package">
```

Comment: I just ran into this and had a similar solve. It's confusing because the line number reported by `aapt dump badging` does not match the line numbers in the manifest you can see in the APK analyzer.